# Salting and hashing functions returning nothing

Tags: php, hash, salt

I found a script that salts, hashes, and then some, but my `$password` returns as the original string when I submit my form. This seems above my "pay grade"... My goal is to insert the returned salt, hash, and other outputs from the script into my db. I'm not even sure what column values I need in the db (MYSQLi). The script is in `if($valid)` before the sql:

```
<?php
if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST")
{$valid = true;

if (empty($_POST["password"]))
{$passwordErr = "Password must be set!"; $Epassword = "nope"; $valid = false;}
if (strpos($_POST["password"], " ") !== false)
{$passwordErr = "No spaces are allowed"; $Epassword = "nope"; $valid = false;}
if(strlen(utf8_decode($_POST['password'])) < 10 || strlen(utf8_decode($_POST['password'])) > 30)
 {$passwordErr = "Password must be between 10 and 30 characters"; $Epassword = "nope"; $valid = false;}
$password = htmlspecialchars($_POST['password']);

$tod = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");
$setdate = date("Y-m-d H:i:s", strtotime("-4 hours", strtotime($tod)));
$today = date("Y-m-d", strtotime("-4 hours", strtotime($tod)));

}

if($valid){

/*
 * Password Hashing With PBKDF2 (http://crackstation.net/hashing-security.htm).
 * Copyright (c) 2013, Taylor Hornby
 * All rights reserved.
 *
 * Redistribution and use in source and binary forms, with or without 
 * modification, are permitted provided that the following conditions are met:
 *
 * 1. Redistributions of source code must retain the above copyright notice, 
 * this list of conditions and the following disclaimer.
 *
 * 2. Redistributions in binary form must reproduce the above copyright notice,
 * this list of conditions and the following disclaimer in the documentation 
 * and/or other materials provided with the distribution.
 *
 * THIS SOFTWARE IS PROVIDED BY THE COPYRIGHT HOLDERS AND CONTRIBUTORS "AS IS" 
 * AND ANY EXPRESS OR IMPLIED WARRANTIES, INCLUDING, BUT NOT LIMITED TO, THE 
 * IMPLIED WARRANTIES OF MERCHANTABILITY AND FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE 
 * ARE DISCLAIMED. IN NO EVENT SHALL THE COPYRIGHT HOLDER OR CONTRIBUTORS BE 
 * LIABLE FOR ANY DIRECT, INDIRECT, INCIDENTAL, SPECIAL, EXEMPLARY, OR 
 * CONSEQUENTIAL DAMAGES (INCLUDING, BUT NOT LIMITED TO, PROCUREMENT OF 
 * SUBSTITUTE GOODS OR SERVICES; LOSS OF USE, DATA, OR PROFITS; OR BUSINESS 
 * INTERRUPTION) HOWEVER CAUSED AND ON ANY THEORY OF LIABILITY, WHETHER IN 
 * CONTRACT, STRICT LIABILITY, OR TORT (INCLUDING NEGLIGENCE OR OTHERWISE) 
 * ARISING IN ANY WAY OUT OF THE USE OF THIS SOFTWARE, EVEN IF ADVISED OF THE 
 * POSSIBILITY OF SUCH DAMAGE.
 */

// These constants may be changed without breaking existing hashes.
define("PBKDF2_HASH_ALGORITHM", "sha256");
define("PBKDF2_ITERATIONS", 1000);
define("PBKDF2_SALT_BYTE_SIZE", 24);
define("PBKDF2_HASH_BYTE_SIZE", 24);

define("HASH_SECTIONS", 4);
define("HASH_ALGORITHM_INDEX", 0);
define("HASH_ITERATION_INDEX", 1);
define("HASH_SALT_INDEX", 2);
define("HASH_PBKDF2_INDEX", 3);

function create_hash($password)
{
// format: algorithm:iterations:salt:hash
$salt = base64_encode(mcrypt_create_iv(PBKDF2_SALT_BYTE_SIZE, MCRYPT_DEV_URANDOM));
return PBKDF2_HASH_ALGORITHM . ":" . PBKDF2_ITERATIONS . ":" .  $salt . ":" .
    base64_encode(pbkdf2(
        PBKDF2_HASH_ALGORITHM,
        $password,
        $salt,
        PBKDF2_ITERATIONS,
        PBKDF2_HASH_BYTE_SIZE,
        true
    ));
}

function validate_password($password, $correct_hash)
{
$params = explode(":", $correct_hash);
if(count($params) < HASH_SECTIONS)
   return false;
$pbkdf2 = base64_decode($params[HASH_PBKDF2_INDEX]);
return slow_equals(
    $pbkdf2,
    pbkdf2(
        $params[HASH_ALGORITHM_INDEX],
        $password,
        $params[HASH_SALT_INDEX],
        (int)$params[HASH_ITERATION_INDEX],
        strlen($pbkdf2),
        true
    )
);
}

// Compares two strings $a and $b in length-constant time.
function slow_equals($a, $b)
{
$diff = strlen($a) ^ strlen($b);
for($i = 0; $i < strlen($a) && $i < strlen($b); $i++)
{
    $diff |= ord($a[$i]) ^ ord($b[$i]);
}
return $diff === 0;
}

/*
* PBKDF2 key derivation function as defined by RSA's PKCS #5: https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2898.txt
 * $algorithm - The hash algorithm to use. Recommended: SHA256
 * $password - The password.
 * $salt - A salt that is unique to the password.
 * $count - Iteration count. Higher is better, but slower. Recommended: At least 1000.
 * $key_length - The length of the derived key in bytes.
 * $raw_output - If true, the key is returned in raw binary format. Hex encoded otherwise.
 * Returns: A $key_length-byte key derived from the password and salt.
 *
 * Test vectors can be found here: https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc6070.txt
 *
 * This implementation of PBKDF2 was originally created by https://defuse.ca
 * With improvements by http://www.variations-of-shadow.com
 */
function pbkdf2($algorithm, $password, $salt, $count, $key_length, $raw_output = false)
{
$algorithm = strtolower($algorithm);
if(!in_array($algorithm, hash_algos(), true))
    trigger_error('PBKDF2 ERROR: Invalid hash algorithm.', E_USER_ERROR);
if($count <= 0 || $key_length <= 0)
    trigger_error('PBKDF2 ERROR: Invalid parameters.', E_USER_ERROR);

if (function_exists("hash_pbkdf2")) {
    // The output length is in NIBBLES (4-bits) if $raw_output is false!
    if (!$raw_output) {
        $key_length = $key_length * 2;
    }
    return hash_pbkdf2($algorithm, $password, $salt, $count, $key_length, $raw_output);
}

$hash_length = strlen(hash($algorithm, "", true));
$block_count = ceil($key_length / $hash_length);

$output = "";
for($i = 1; $i <= $block_count; $i++) {
    // $i encoded as 4 bytes, big endian.
    $last = $salt . pack("N", $i);
    // first iteration
    $last = $xorsum = hash_hmac($algorithm, $last, $password, true);
    // perform the other $count - 1 iterations
    for ($j = 1; $j < $count; $j++) {
        $xorsum ^= ($last = hash_hmac($algorithm, $last, $password, true));
    }
    $output .= $xorsum;
}

if($raw_output)
    return substr($output, 0, $key_length);
else
    return bin2hex(substr($output, 0, $key_length));
}

$sqli = @mysqli_connect("host", "db", "pass","empty");
if (mysqli_connect_errno($sqli)) { echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error(); }

mysqli_query($sqli, "INSERT INTO `table`(`password`) VALUES ('$password')");
?>
```

Note: the query inserts the original `$password` value into the db.

The query inserts the original `$password` value into the db.

**[Note]**
@Masoud answered my question, but I ended up using `password_hash($_POST['password'], PASSWORD_DEFAULT)' suggested by @martinstoeckli as follows:

```
if($valid){

$hashed_password = password_hash($_POST['password'], PASSWORD_DEFAULT);

mysqli_query($sqli, "INSERT INTO `table`(`password`) VALUES ('$hashed_password')");

}
```

Comment: Can you post the code where you are using this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It must insert original $password to database, because you are not change $password from start to end of your code.
one way is to call the "pbkdf2" function like this before last line of your code (before "mysqli_query(..." ) :

```
<?php
$hashed_password = pbkdf2(PBKDF2_HASH_ALGORITHM,$password,'dsafdsa',10,5,false)
?>
```

And change last line of your code like this:

```
mysqli_query($sqli, "INSERT INTO `table`(`password`) VALUES ('$hashed_password')");
```

Comment: Using this did change the password, but it is only 10 characters. Can you please explain why it is not much longer. I expected it to be at least 256 characters. Note: I added a semi-colon to the pbhdf2 call.

Comment: The fourth parameter of "pbkdf2()" function get the length of password and I set it to 10, you can change it to 256. like this:
$hashed_password = pbkdf2(PBKDF2_HASH_ALGORITHM,$password,'dsafdsa',256,5,false)

Comment: Is there any advantage or disadvantage to using longer/shorter password lengths? It baffles me as to how the original password value can be stored, regardless of the length. Also, in your suggested call, what does the "5" represent? I don't fully understand pbkdf2.

Answer (score 1):

This problem can be solved much easier with PHP's function [password_hash()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php). This function will return a 60 character string, including the hash, the salt and the cost factor, you can store this string into a single field in your database. To check against a stored hash you would use the function [password_verify()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.password-verify.php).

```
// Hash a new password for storing in the database.
// The function automatically generates a cryptographically safe salt.
$hashToStoreInDb = password_hash($password, PASSWORD_BCRYPT);

// Check if the hash of the entered login password, matches the stored hash.
// The salt and the cost factor will be extracted from $existingHashFromDb.
$isPasswordCorrect = password_verify($password, $existingHashFromDb);
```

In your code you are also checking certain conditions and escape the password with htmlspecialchars(). This is not necessary and should not be done, the only requirement that makes sense for passwords is a minimum length. Escaping is not necessary because you will feed the content to the hash function and its output will always be safe (however it would have to be done for SQL not for HTML output). Variables in $_POST will already be decoded by PHP.

```
if (!isset($_POST["password"]) || strlen($_POST["password"]) < 10)
{
  // password is invalid show error message
}
```

To prevent a misunderstanding, password hashing is always done server side, so the password will be transported plain text between client and server. The usual solution to handle this problem is using HTTPS, SSL will then encrypt the password before sending it over the internet.

Comment: This looks much simpler. If I read the documentation properly, `PASSWORD_BCRYPT` produces a result with length of 60 characters. What field type and length is recommended to store results in mysqldb? I noticed when I use binary or varbinary field types, the result seems to be "re-hashed" when inserted. As for the htmlspecialchars(), I was echoing the password into the value (yes, like a noob), and I forgot to remove it! :D

Comment: @bcintegrity - To store the password hash, you can make a field of type varchar(60). To be prepared for future improvements you could choose a length of varchar(255) and use the default algorithm `password_hash($password, PASSWORD_DEFAULT)`.

Comment: The word "default" makes `PASSWORD_DEFAULT` sound sub par, but after reading the docs again, it seems like the better option. Thank you! I selected @Masoud's answer because he answered the original question. In the next few days I will implement your suggestion, and edit my original post to reflect your contribution :)